# Red5: how to enable RTMPT?

Tags: red5

I install Red5 1.0 RC1 from the [official site](http://wiki.red5.org/wiki/1_0_RC1), but it doesn't have RTMPT enabled by default. How do I enable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution: take the latest version from SVN:

```
svn checkout http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/java/server/trunk/ red5-read-only
```

Then, in the conf/jee-container.xml uncomment the following section:

```
    <!-- RTMPT (dedicated server) -->

    <bean id="rtmpt.server" class="org.red5.server.tomcat.rtmpt.RTMPTLoader" init-method="init" lazy-init="true">
    ...
```

Comment: Note that is only for a dedicated RTMPT instance which would probably used twice as much in the way of resources. The way I would suggest is to use the RTMPT servlet approach shown here: http://gregoire.org/2009/01/28/rtmpt-and-red5/

Comment: The RTMPT bean doesn't appear to exist in conf/jee-container.xml in the latest svn version. Can you confirm @Mondain?

Comment: That is correct; I suggest using the servlet in your app, or adjust the old bean to fit the new style of configuration for the tomcat.server bean.